# how to wait for getting all mail items?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on outlook addin and have to call another funcion after collecting all to, cc, bcc
I want to process all information with to1, cc1, bcc1 but
After the toRecipients.getAsync() is called, the control returns to process function and to1 is empty.

How do I handle this ?

Also within getAllRecipients(), after the getAsync() is called, variables 'to1' / 'cc1' / 'bcc1' outside its scope (getAsync) are empty.

Any better way to handle both the above cases ?

Please see the below  function and callers

```js
function getAllRecipients(event) {

  var to1 = [];
  var cc1 = [];
  var bcc1 = [];

  // Local objects to point to recipients of either
  // the appointment or message that is being composed.
  // bccRecipients applies to only messages, not appointments.
  var toRecipients, ccRecipients, bccRecipients;

  item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

  // Verify if the composed item is an appointment or message.
  if (item.itemType == Office.MailboxEnums.ItemType.Appointment) {
    toRecipients = item.requiredAttendees;
    ccRecipients = item.optionalAttendees;
  } else {
    toRecipients = item.to;
    ccRecipients = item.cc;
    bccRecipients = item.bcc;
  }

  
  // Use asynchronous method getAsync to get each type of recipients
  // of the composed item. Each time, this example passes an anonymous 
  // callback function that doesn't take any parameters.
  if (toRecipients) {
    toRecipients.getAsync(function (asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
        console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
      }
      else {
        // Async call to get to-recipients of the item completed.
        // Display the email addresses of the to-recipients. 
        console.log('To-recipients of the item:');
        for (var i = 0; i < asyncResult.value.length; i++) {
            var mailID = asyncResult.value[i].emailAddress;
            to1.push(mailID);
        }
      }    
    }); // End getAsync for to-recipients.
  }


  // Get any cc-recipients.
  if (ccRecipients) {
    ccRecipients.getAsync(function(asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
      } else {
        // Async call to get cc-recipients of the item completed.
        // Display the email addresses of the cc-recipients.
        console.log("Cc-recipients of the item:");
        for (var i = 0; i < asyncResult.value.length; i++) {
            var mailID = asyncResult.value[i].emailAddress;
            cc1.push(mailID);
        }
      }
    }); // End getAsync for cc-recipients.
  }

  // If the item has the bcc field, i.e., item is message,
  // get any bcc-recipients.
  if (bccRecipients) {
    bccRecipients.getAsync(function(asyncResult) {
      if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
        console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
      } else {
        // Async call to get bcc-recipients of the item completed.
        // Display the email addresses of the bcc-recipients.
        console.log("Bcc-recipients of the item:");
        for (var i = 0; i < asyncResult.value.length; i++) {
            var mailID = asyncResult.value[i].emailAddress;
            bcc1.push(mailID);
        }
      }
    }); // End getAsync for bcc-recipients.
  }

  return to1;
}

getAllRecipients(event);
process(to1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The recipient APIs for compose are asynchronous, so you will need to await the resolved value from the API.

There is some documentation about asynchronous programming with Office add-ins and some common patterns with asynchronous functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/asynchronous-programming-in-office-add-ins#asynchronous-programming-patterns).